# Safari float or sizing issue for tiles

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, masonry

I've been mocking up this portfolio in CodePen and it is working beautifully... except for in Safari.

http://codepen.io/tpalmer75/pen/FijEh (SASS for just one .item element)

```
.item
  width: calc(100% / 3)
  display: inline-block
  height: 0
  padding-bottom: 25%
  background-position: center center
  cursor: pointer
  overflow: hidden
  background-size: cover
```

I have tried messing with the CSS calc functions, the box sizing, the float, and more.Here is what it looks like in Chrome and Firefox.

[image: chrome screenshot]

And here in Safari:

[image: safari screenshot]

Any ideas?

Code: http://codepen.io/tpalmer75/pen/FijEh

*EDIT*

The problem is resulting from safari rounding down to a whole pixel for all percentages. How can I fix this, and only target Safari?

Comment: Not that this solves any problems, but `100%/3` is a static number, why would you use `calc`?

Comment: Not a whole number, though. I find it nicer than declaring `width: 33.33333333%`. But herein lies the issue, but Safari is declaring it as 33px pixels rather than 33.3px or 33.5px.

Comment: It's not only not nicer, but it's a hugely unnecessary drag on performance.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, and I suppose that the browser can only break down pixels so far. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two potential solutions to your problem:

### Use ems rather than percentages

I have been able to overcome this issue by utilizing a technique similar to Squeezemod http://codepen.io/makerbox/pen/xksiK - it uses javascript to get the width and height of the browser window and then breaks it down into ems:

```
//set function to get the size of 1em depending on browser aspect and size
function squeezemod(){
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var skinnyem = windowWidth / 95;
var fatem = windowHeight / 45;
var ratio = windowWidth / windowHeight;
if (ratio<2.1){
var emval = skinnyem;
}else{
var emval = fatem;
};
$("body").css({"font-size": emval + "px"});
};

//on resize do these functions
$(window).resize(function(){
squeezemod();
});
```

You'll need to initialize the function in your HTML head too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//squeezemod();
</script>
```

Everything sized using ems will resize according to the size of the browser window. It changes according to the width to height ratio too.

You may need to fiddle with the calculation to get it to work right for you. The Squeezemod fix was never 100%.

### or, use a safari specific border

by using javascript, set browser specific styles to your item class:

```
if ( $.browser.safari ){
$(".item").css('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
};
```

xxxxxx is where you define the style e.g. margin 1px
Utilize this to add the width that Safari has taken off in whichever way suits your items - margin, border, etc. You could even just redefine the width completely for Safari only using this method.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I will try to explore these different options. The math gets very complicated when you get down to the pixel, though.

Comment: I've worked up a nasty but working solution by subtracting 4 pixels from each grid item.

http://codepen.io/tpalmer75/pen/FijEh?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

The issues are caused by all off the calc() functions and percentages used to make the grid.

I'm detecting the browser with jQuery and subtracting 4 pixels from each item to compensate.

http://codepen.io/tpalmer75/pen/FijEh?editors=101

```
 // Find Safari Browser and exclude Chrome, iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch which all contain 'Safari' in the user agent
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && !navigator.userAgent.match(/(Chrome|iPad|iPhone|iPod Touch)/) ) { 

    alert('You are using Safari desktop.')

    var item = $('.item');
    var page = $('#page');

      item.width(function(){
        return $(this).width() - 4;
      });

      page.width(function() {
        return $(this).width() + 8;
      });

      $(window).resize(function() {


        item.css('width', '');
        page.css('width', '');

        item.width(function(){
          return $(this).width() - 4;
        });

        page.width(function() {
          return $(this).width() + 8;
        });


      });
  }
```